# Operation With SQL and Date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm a newbye in the operation with SQL on date.

However,I need to do a query that return record filter by X date < or > of 30 days or similar.

I have this query for now:

```
SELECT nome_prodotto,quantita 
FROM prodotti 
LEFT JOIN acquisti 
    ON prodotti.id_prodotto = acquisti.id_prodotto
```

my goal is get the product that aren't bought in last 30 days or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date field in `acquisti` is called `date_acquisti`, products not bought in the last 30 days will be queried like this:

```
SELECT nome_prodotto,quantita 
FROM prodotti 
LEFT JOIN acquisti 
    ON (prodotti.id_prodotto = acquisti.id_prodotto
        AND acquisti.date_acquisti > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
where acquisti.id_prodotto is NULL
```

The trick is using the JOIN `condition` to get only the product acquisitions in the last 30 days. Since this is a `LEFT JOIN`, any row in result set where `acquisti.id_prodotto` is `NULL` means the product was not purchased in that period.

Comment: GREAT! THANKS! BUT..ONE QUESTION: why I need to use AND after I have used a Left Join??? ..IT'S the first time that i see a AND clause in the join clause

Comment: @Seojudo the AND after the LEFT JOIN means that you are joining on both the id_prodotto and the records that meet the date criteria.  You could also place that in the WHERE clause

Comment: What @bluefeet said :) I could've used parenthesis, so it would be more evident

Answer (score 2):

```
 WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) =< your_date;
```

Comment: OP wants products not bought in last 30 days. This is a LEFT JOIN. If you filter in `WHERE` clause, products not bought at all will be left out, but they are supposed to appear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_add` function to achieve this

Ex:

```
x_date between DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) and NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,

`where myDate between some_date and some_other_date`

may help you in other similar situations.